# Animation with gnuplot : only one cruve plotted in an animation whereas 2 expected

Tags: animation, plot, ffmpeg, png, gnuplot

I have the following script which is expected to produce the animations of 2 curves :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..397}; do
gnuplot -p <<-EOFMarker
set terminal png;
set output "pic$i.png";
set title "power spectrum";
set xlabel "scale (k)";
set ylabel "P(k)";
set key top left;
set grid;
set ytics out nomirror;
set xtics out nomirror;
set logscale x;
set logscale y;
set format x "10^{%L}";
set yrange [0:30000];
plot "CAMB-1.3.5/matter_camb$i" u 1:2 w l;
replot "EFTCAMB_v3_beta/matter_eftcamb$i" u 1:2 w l;
EOFMarker
done

# Build movie with ffmpeg
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -i pic%d.png  movie.mpeg
```

Every works fine excepted the fact that only one curve is plotted in animation (CAMB-1.3.5) :

Here is an example of frame :

[image]

Why the "`replot`" command is not taken into account in the generated image ?

Comment: What do you actually want to plot? Your two files in one graph (here: frame)? What is the reason for using replot? Check `help plot`.

Comment: @theozh I have 2 experimental curves to plot. Interactively, when I do `plot`for the first one and `replot` for the second one, both appear on the graph but impossible to reproduce it with this script above : only one curve appear, I don't know why ? Regards

Comment: you can plot two files in one graph like this: `plot FILE1 u 1:2 w l, FILE2 u 1:2 w l`. Check `help plot`.

Comment: You cannot stuff two images into a single png file.  The "replot" would work, but you would have to specify a new png file to put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of the SO-rule "no answer in comments":

Check `help plot`:

> ```
> Syntax: 
>
>       plot {<ranges>} <plot-element> {, <plot-element>, <plot-element>}
> ```

> ```
> Examples: 
>
>       plot sin(x)
>       plot sin(x), cos(x)
>       plot f(x) = sin(x*a), a = .2, f(x), a = .4, f(x)
>       plot "datafile.1" with lines, "datafile.2" with points
>       plot [t=1:10] [-pi:pi*2] tan(t), \
>            "data.1" using (tan($2)):($3/$4) smooth csplines \
>                     axes x1y2 notitle with lines 5
>       plot for [datafile in "spinach.dat broccoli.dat"] datafile
> ```